# C++11: Returning std::unique_ptr with Custom Lambda Deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr

**Question:**

Does anyone know of a way to return a `std::unique_ptr` which uses a custom deleter defined as a lambda?  Failing that, does anyone know of a better overall approach to the below problem?

**Background:**

I am working on a C++11 database connection pool.  The idea is fairly simple, however I seem to be stuck on the actual connection pointer returning.

The overall design of my connection pool is to pre-create a number of connections which are stored in a `std::vector` along with a `bool` to indicate if the given connection is available:

```
static std::vector<std::pair<DataStore*, bool>> connList;
```

The plan is to, on request, return `std::unique_ptr` objects with a custom deleter.  This deleter will not actually free the connection but, instead, will reset the `bool` to allow the connection to be handed out to subsequent requesters.  In this way, consumers of the class don't have to remember to release the connection object.

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to actually return this `std::unique_ptr` with the associated deleter, which is specified in a template parameter.  AFAIK, a lambda is the only way to capture the vector index needed to reset the `bool`.  My current implementation of this lambda is simple:

```
auto connDeleter = [index](DataStore* p) { connList[index].second = true; };
```

And my attempted solution:

```
return std::unique_ptr<DataStore, decltype(connDeleter)>
    (connList[index].first, connDeleter);
```

Unfortunately, this requires all external consumers of the class to know about `connDeleter`, which doesn't make any sense as `index` and `connList` have no meaning outside of the function in question.

AFAIK, any of the other solutions (functors or free functions) will not allow me to receive any kind of index to reset the connection.  I could wrap the pointer and index in an intermediate object and override the dereference operator to "pass through" to the underlying pointer.  This would allow me to update / extract whatever  from the intermediate object however this feels really hacky to me.  Also not sure about the performance impact of an extra object.

**Further Information:**

- This pool will be concurrently accessed via many threads.  Database operations are not homogeneous so connections can be returned in any order.
- I would prefer to hide as much of this deleter business from the consumer.
- For my application, speed is more important that space.

Comment: lamba is basically a compiler-generated function. You can write your own delete function visible for outside code and keeping `index`.

Comment: What is wrong on using `std::function<void(DataStore*)>` as type of pointer with the deleter?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'd say that the use of `::std::function` in this case will lead to additional overhead, both memory and computational.

Comment: A potential danger of using a lambda here is dangling references, as the deleter could be invoked in a different context. If the class of object uses the RAII idiom, a custom deleter should be unnecessary.

Comment: As you don't care about memory management being done with the return value: I would recommend to write your own wrapper that stores the index and maybe even the pointer itself and use RAII to update the bool value.

Comment: And I would recommend to use something like `struct ConnectionEntry { DataStore* pDataStore; bool bFree; };` instead of `std::pair<DataStore*, bool>` for better readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest an approach with manually written deleter. Unlike the approach utilizing `::std::function` this one should not suffer from overhead compared to lambda:

```
class
t_MyDeleter
{
    private: ::std::size_t m_index;

    private: t_MyDeleter(void) = delete;

    public: t_MyDeleter(t_MyDeleter const & that) noexcept: m_index{that.m_index} {}

    public: explicit t_MyDeleter(::std::size_t const index) noexcept: m_index{index} {}

    public: void operator ()(DataStore * const p_store) const
    {
        static_cast<void>(p_store); // not used?
        // don't we also need to keep a reference to connList?
        connList[m_index].second = true;
    }
};

using
t_UniquePointerToDataStore = ::std::unique_ptr<DataStore, t_MyDeleter>;

t_UniquePointerToDataStore
Make_DataStore(void)
{
    ::std::size_t index{};
    return(t_UniquePointerToDataStore{connList[index].first, t_MyDeleter{index}});
}
```

Also with C++14 automatic return type deduction for functions it would be possible to use the lamba without any changes:

```
auto
Make_DataStore(void)
{
    auto connDeleter = [index](DataStore* p) { connList[index].second = true; };
    return(::std::unique_ptr<DataStore, decltype(connDeleter)>{connList[index].first, connDeleter});
}
```

Comment: Huh, that makes sense.  Why define a copy constructor?  I thought that a `unique_ptr` couldn't be copied?  Presumably this would included the deleter object?  Additionally, in answer to your questions in comments, `connList` is statically defined and so shouldn't need to be passed around.

Comment: @phobos51594 Since deleter object is stored inside of `unique_ptr` it is required to be nothrow copy or move constructable and assignable. When constructor is invoke a deleter will be copied from the temp object passed. When `unique_ptr` objects are moved deleter will be copied again.

Comment: I see.  Could I save a few extra cycles by defining move constructor + assignment instead or is the overhead negligible?  From your description it sounds like I have the choice of copy or move and move is *usually* faster.

Comment: @phobos51594 Defining move constructor for `t_MyDeleter` won't really bring any benefits because it will still copy that single `size_t` field.

Answer (score 2):

Even if I would prefer the custom deleter class, other possibility, which hides the deleter is to use `std::shared_ptr` (so has more overhead than `std::unique_ptr`):

```
std::shared_ptr<DataStore> MakeDataStore(int index)
{
    auto connDeleter = [index](DataStore* p) { connList[index].second = true; };

    return std::shared_ptr<DataStore>(connList[index].first, connDeleter);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't returning a `shared_ptr` allow consumers to also duplicate the returned connection pointer?

Comment: You could have indeed several owner then (pointing to the same DataStore).

Comment: This may be diverging toward the software engineering side of StackExchange but, which is best practice?  I feel like the tight lifecycle management of connection objects is 'cleaner' but this does imply that there will be more calls to get / release connections.  Though, overall, is this effort just micro-managing the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` as the type of the deleter in `std::unique_ptr`.

```
std::unique_ptr<DataStore, std::function<void(DataStore*)>> get_ptr()
{
    auto deleter = [index](DataStore*) {
        connList[index].second = true;
    });
    return std::unique_ptr<DataStore, std::function<void(DataStore*)>>(new DataStore(), deleter)
}
```

And tell your users to use

```
using managed_ptr = std::unique_ptr<DataStore, std::function<void(DataStore*)>>;
```

Comment: Note that compared to functor or lamba use of `std::function` will require extra memory (on 32-bit VS2017 `std::function` instance is 40 bytes while functor is ony 4 bytes) and some extra overhead for each call.